# how do I write function to split in subsets;

Tags: kdb

how do I subset a list of 9 elements in to 2 3 4 subsets as below?

I tried below piece of code. please help me to write function.
1st solution I tried

```
q)list
`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i
q)list 0+til 2
`a`b
q)list 2+til 3
`c`d`e
q)list 3+til 4
`d`e`f`g
```

2nd solution I tried, this is not giving expected result because in range function x argument I am unable to change dynamically.

```
q)range:{x+til 1+abs[y-x]}
q)func:{[x;y] :raze(x range[0;y-1])}
q)func/:[list;2 3 4]
`a`b
`a`b`c
`a`b`c`d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cut/

```
q)0 2 5_`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i
`a`b
`c`d`e
`f`g`h`i
```

**EDIT:**

As a function:

```
q){x _y}[0 2 5;`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i]
`a`b
`c`d`e
`f`g`h`i
```

If you want to pass 2 3 4 as an argument:

```
q){(-1_0,sums x)_y}[2 3 4;`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i]
`a`b
`c`d`e
`f`g`h`i
```

Comment: Hi Neil, Thank you for  prompt response. Please help with a function to pass indexes dynamically. 2 3 4 or 2 2 5.

Comment: Made an edit to my answer.